# PHP Email form not working properly

Tags: php, forms, email

I am very new at php but even so, this does not make any sense to me:
I have an HTML page containing the php form as follows:
...

```
    <article id="content"><div class="ic">Here comes the contact form!</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Contact form</h2>
    <form method="post" id="ContactForm" name="myemailform" action="sendemail.php">
    <div>
    <div  class="wrapper">
    <span>Nume:</span>
    <div class="bg"><input type="text" class="input" name="myname"></div>
    </div>
    <div  class="wrapper">
    <span>Adresa:</span>
    <div class="bg"><input type="text" class="input" name="myadresa"   ></div>                              
    </div>
    <div  class="wrapper">
    <span>Email:</span>
    <div class="bg"><input type="text" class="input" name="myemail"  ></div>                                
    </div>
    <div  class="textarea_box">
    <span>Mesaj:</span>
    <div class="bg"><textarea name="textarea" cols="1" rows="1" name="mymesaj"></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="button1" name='submit' value="submit" onclick='javascript: document.myemailform.binset=2; document.myemailform.submit();'>Send message</a>  
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </article>
```

And the action sendemail.php is as follows:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "myreal_email@email.com";
$email_subject = "Message from contact form";

function died($error) {
// your error code can go here
echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
echo $error."<br /><br />";
echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['myname']) ||
!isset($_POST['myadresa']) ||
!isset($_POST['myemail']) ||
!isset($_POST['mymesaj'])) {
died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
}

$first_name = $_POST['myname']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['myadresa']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['myemail']; // required
$comments = $_POST['mymesaj']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Adresa: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Mesaj efectiv: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>
<!-- include your own success html here -->
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
<?php
}
    ?>
```

Now, the problem is that I receive the email, the subject is ok, the sender email is ok, but the message is empty... no $email_message is received. 
Why is this happening?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Check output of `$email_message` just before the mail sent.

Comment: echo $email_message before sending mail, and check if the variable contains the message.

Comment: Your `clean_string()` function will fail to remove those items where the target is capitalised (i.e. 'Bcc:' or 'Cc:' etc.)  Your regex intended to validate email addresses will fail addresses like myname@example.co.uk or myname@email.example.com. All this filtering is necessary, but can be better done by `filter_input_array()`, and finally, telling someone their name is invalid is, at best, impolite!

Comment: Remove the `@` from mail command and see what error is throwing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is with your

```
  <textarea name="textarea" cols="1" rows="1" name="mymesaj"></textarea>
```

there are two names with the textarea check it.

```
 <textarea  cols="1" rows="1" name="mymesaj"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you Nomi for your observation. You were partially right. However, there seems to be a problem with 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) . I think submit is not POSTED. I replaced 'submit' with 'myemail' after fixing what Nomi noticed and now it works. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

if you are usinh HTML 5 or higher version...use 'required' in the input tags...which will automatically validate the input data is present or not...

like this:

```
<input type="text" class="input" name="myname"  required>
```

and for email validation give the input type as email...not text

like this:

```
<input type="email" class="input" name="myemail" required >
```

Also try ajax,jquery for further form validations..

Comment: Prem, I do not see the code because you did not format it correctly. You must leave a blank row before code and the code must be indented 8 spaces in order to be shown uninterpreted.