# how to send mail in php?

Tags: php, html, windows, phpmyadmin

can anyone provide me the way of sending mail through php with attached object as well .plz i am new in this kindly help me in this. is there any server to be installed for this? the mail should this on any email account aswell plz help me in this.can any one provide me the link of tutorial i used the tutorial [HERE](http://deepakssn.blogspot.com/2006/06/gmail-php-send-email-using-php-with.html) it display me the error  `Fatal error: Call to undefined function IsSMTP() in C:\wamp\www\EMS3\mail.php on line 13` plz help me in this

Comment: Suugested you to please visit this website http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sending_emails.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Email form not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269066/php-email-form-not-working-properly)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269066/php-email-form-not-working-properly i am using this but its not working @nAvEeD

Comment: @ashy1234 we are just suggesting you the reference posts

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the example provided there. Use the following code.

```
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password
$webmaster_email = "username@doamin.com"; //Reply to this email ID
$email="username@domain.com"; // Recipients email ID
$name="name"; // Recipient's name
$mail->From = $webmaster_email;
$mail->FromName = "Webmaster";
$mail->AddAddress($email,$name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"Webmaster");
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
$mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz"); // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg"); // attachment
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
$mail->Subject = "This is the subject";
$mail->Body = "Hi,
This is the HTML BODY "; //HTML Body
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body when user views in plain text format"; //Text Body
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

update you also need to set the external SMTP server your using. if your using google. i believe its `smtp.gmail.com`

```
  $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->Port = 465;
  $mail->Secure = "ssl";
```

Comment: updated the answer take a look for more setting u need for gmail

Comment: put it below `$mail->SMTPAuth = true; `

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external PHP library for sending mail, which I have used internally on a localhost, but still configured the parameters to send to external sources.  The package is [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Answer (score -3):

In localhost you can't send any mail. After hosting only this is possible.

Comment: read the entire question OP is using a library. you can also send email from localhost using an external smtp server.

Comment: @ashy1234 I think may be it is network connection problem. Please Check your network properly connected. And also Thank you for your information Mr.@DevZer0